# putty command line arguments acting strangely with java

Tags: java, putty

I need my code to read in a file pathway and analyze the file at the end of it, and according to the assignment it has to exit if no valid pathway is given. when I type in something like "java ClassName pathway/file" though it just goes to accepting more input. If I then put in the exact same pathway it does what I want it to but it need to do it in the former format. should I not be using a Scanner? 
(TextFileAnalyzer is another class I wrote that does the file analysis, obviously)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String path = null;
        TextFileAnalyzer analysis = null;
        if (args.length == 0 || java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(args[0].charAt(0)))
            System.exit(1);
        try {
            path = stdin.next();
            analysis = new TextFileAnalyzer(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(path + ": No such file or directory");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        System.out.println(analysis);
        stdin.close();
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it needs to do it in the "former format" are you saying the input must look like `java ClassName filepath/file` and you will then, from that input, parse the file out of the `filepath/file`?

Comment: yea exactly. it does seem to recognize the 'filepath/file' part as something because without it it just exits, as per the if statement, but it doesnt really do anything with it until I type it in again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments specified on the command line are not the same as information entered via standard input at the console. Reading from `System.in` will let you read input, and this is not related to command line parameters.

The problem with your current, non-working code is that while you are checking to see if the argument was specified, you aren't actually using `args[0]` as the pathname, you're just going on to read user input regardless.

Command line parameters are passed in via the `String[]` parameter to main. In your case it's the first parameter, so it would be in `args[0]`:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   String pathname;
   if (args.length > 0) {
       pathname = args[0]; // from the command line
   } else {
       // get pathname from somewhere else, e.g. read from System.in
   }
}
```

Or, more strict:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   String pathname;
   if (args.length > 1) {
       System.err.println("Error: Too many command line parameters.");
       System.exit(1);
   } else if (args.length > 0) {
       pathname = args[0]; // from the command line
   } else {
       // get pathname from somewhere else, e.g. read from System.in
   }
}
```

Check out the [official tutorial on command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more information.

---

By the way, I noticed you have this in your `if` condition:

```
java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(args[0].charAt(0))
```

Leading and trailing whitespace is automatically trimmed off of unquoted command line parameters, so that will always be `false` unless the user explicitly uses quotes and does something like:

```
java ClassName "   something"
```

And even in that case, you may want to just accept it and use `args[0].trim()` to be more lenient.

Comment: ahhhhhhh yes this worked perfectly thank you so much (the assignment is due in an hour).